# Android init service error invalid keyword 'u:object_r:system_file:s0

Tags: android, shell, service, init, selinux

I want to run a service on few tablets (VONINO NAVO P) that they will serve as a photo frame for digital ads.
What i'm trying to achieve is to run some commands at boot and i'm stuck.
I have created digitalads.rc in system/etc/init which will execute /system/bin/digitalads.sh from where i need to run some commands like:

```
svc power stayon true
settings put system screen_brightness 255
pm disable com.android.systemui
settings put system screen_off_timeout 999999999
settings put system accelerometer_rotation 0
settings put global airplane_mode_on 0
svc bluetooth disable
monkey -p my.app -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
and some other custom commands that they will update the contents of media files
```

my .rc file:

```
tulip-f708:/ # cat /system/etc/init/digitalads.rc                                                                          
service digitalads /system/bin/digitalads.sh
    disabled
    user root
    group root
    u:object_r:system_file:s0

on property:sys.boot_completed=1
   start digitalads
```

dmesg output

```
tulip-f708:/ # dmesg | grep digitalads                                                                                     
[    6.512868] init: /system/etc/init/digitalads.rc: 5: invalid keyword 'u:object_r:system_file:s0'
[    6.522694] init: (Parsing /system/etc/init/digitalads.rc took 0.01s.)
[   44.546434] init: Service digitalads does not have a SELinux domain defined.
```

SElinux output

```
tulip-f708:/ # getenforce 
Enforcing
tulip-f708:/ # setenforce 0
tulip-f708:/ # getenforce                                                                                                  
Permissive
```

other services run under u:object_r:system_file:s0

```
tulip-f708:/ # ls -Z /system/bin/                                                                                          
u:object_r:system_file:s0           4d78d2ea-a631-70fb-aaa787c2b5773052.ta 
u:object_r:system_file:s0           a98befed-d679-ce4a-a3c827dcd51d21ed.ta 
u:object_r:system_file:s0           acpi                                   
u:object_r:system_file:s0           am                                     
u:object_r:system_file:s0           app_process                            
u:object_r:zygote_exec:s0           app_process32                          
u:object_r:zygote_exec:s0           app_process64                          
u:object_r:system_file:s0           applypatch                             
u:object_r:system_file:s0           appops                                 
u:object_r:system_file:s0           appwidget                              
u:object_r:system_file:s0           arping 
.............................
```

I also tried to unpack boot.img to modify init.rc but failed when put it back (bricked two of them). Not mention that to root them i had to contact the manufacturer directly...

Some hints would help me! Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `.rc` files misses the `seclabel` keyword. Your service declaration should look like this:

```
service digitalads /system/bin/digitalads.sh
    disabled
    user root
    group root
    seclabel u:object_r:system_file:s0
```

---

Edit regarding your SE Linux violation: The message says that init cannot start a program labelled with system_file. That means you have to modify the SE Linux rules. The best approach would be to add a new label specific to your service:

- Identify the folder where you want to add your policy. This is somewhat specific to your setup, so I cannot give you a definite answer. Check for `.te` files in your source code. The core Android policies are in `system/sepolicy/`, but if your setup has special SE policies somewhere in `devices/` or `vendor/`, these location would be better suited for your customization (because it makes it easier for your to update to a new Android version when your customizations are as isolated as possible).
- In that folder, create a new policy file, e.g. `digitalads.te`. Add the following rules:

```
type digitalads_exec, system_file_type, exec_type, file_type;
type digitalads domain;
init_daemon_domain(digitalads)
```

- In the same folder, there should be a file `file_contexts`: Add a line like

```
/system/bin/digitalads u:object_r:digitalads_exec:s0
```

- (When you boot with this change, `ls -Z /system/bin/digitalads` should show this label.)
- For the seclabel in your `.rc` file, replace `system_file` with `digitalads`.
- (Check `dmesg` output and also `ps -Z` to verify your service has been labelled correctly.)

Comment: [  420.798959] init: cannot execve('/system/bin/digitalads.sh'): Permission denied
[  420.808120] init: Service 'digitalads' (pid 3383) exited with status 127
[  420.818030] init: Service 'digitalads' (pid 3383) killing any children in process group
[  425.832436] init: Starting service 'digitalads'...
[  425.840864] type=1400 audit(1262542213.780:80): avc: denied { transition } for pid=3384 comm="init" path="/system/bin/digitalads.sh" dev="nandd" ino=2461 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_file:s0 tclass=process permissive=0

Comment: This basically means init isn't allowed to start a service with this label. I will extend my answer on how to extend the rules.